# Only handle mouse events in a specific region

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a Hexagon widget, using a CustomPainter, and, using that, I make a Honeycomb widget like

[image]

Now, I want to be able to click on an individual Hexagon.  The problem is that the Hexagon widget is basically a rectangular widget and hence it overlaps partly with other hexagons in the honeycomb structure.

I can add a GestureDetector around the Hexagon widget but this handles all clicks in the rectangle. So I would like to ignore clicks that are outside the hexagon itself and let the mouse clicks be handled by the underlying hexagon.

Is this possible?

Comment: pls add some code for reference?

Comment: Consider including a minimal snippet that will reproduce the issue

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, `CustomPainter`has a `hitTest` method so the following code snippet seems to work.

(Thanks to ChatGPT for pointing me in the right direction although initially it stubbornly claimed that hitTest was a property of the `CustomPaint` widget)

```
class HexagonPainter extends CustomPainter {
  Path hexagonPath = Path();

  @override
  bool? hitTest(Offset position) {
    //check if click is inside hexagon
    return hexagonPath.contains(position);
  }

  ...
```